# Extarcting only the city and pincode from the address given in pandas column python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, data-science

How to extract only the pin-code and city from the address given and in particular column and assign it into two new pandas columns named as 'city' and 'address'. This is working fine with the regex in python pandas , is there any other quick way to run since it takes more than 6 min for 10000 rows.

Example address:`87 F/F  Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar  NA  Delhi 110059 Delhi`

```
pincoderegex=re.compile(r'([\w]*)[\s]([\d]{6})')
pincoderegex.search(ref).group()  --- > o/p : 'Delhi 110059'
pincoderegex.search(data_rnr['BORROWER ADDRESS'][80]).groups()[1] ---> o/p:'700105'
data_rnr['BORROWER CITY_NAME']='default value'
data_rnr['BORROWER CITY_PINCODE']='default value'
for i in range(0,len(data_rnr['BORROWER ADDRESS'])):
    try:
        data_rnr['BORROWER CITY_NAME'][i]=pincoderegex.search(data_rnr['BORROWER ADDRESS'][i]).groups()[0]
        data_rnr['BORROWER CITY_PINCODE'][i]=pincoderegex.search(data_rnr['BORROWER ADDRESS'][i]).groups()[1]
    except TypeError:
        print('TypeError')
    except NameError:
        print('NameError')
    except AttributeError:
        print('AttributeError')
    except:
        pass
```

The output will be added in the new Df columns `data_rnr['BORROWER CITY_NAME']` and `data_rnr['BORROWER CITY_PINCODE']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Olivier Hao's answer which gives you the best pattern: `\s([\w]+)\s([\d]{6})`, you could have a faster one line code using only Pandas:

```
pd.concat([data_rnr, data_rnr['BORROWER ADDRESS'].str.extract(r'\s(?P<BORROWER_CITY_NAME>[\w]+)\s(?P<BORROWER_CITY_PINCODE>[\d]{6})')], axis=1)
```

Notice that I directly named the groups in the regex pattern to create the new columns.

The only difference with your code is that instead of `default value` in the new column create, you would have `NaN` values where the pattern was not found.

I used this sample of Data:

```
data = [
    "87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Delhi 110059 Delhi",
    "87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Paris 930000 Paris",
    "87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Somewhere 115800 Somewhere",
    "Wrong stuff",
    "87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Bombay 148444 Bombay",
]
```

Using your code and after changing the pattern and removing the prints that take a lot of computation time I got this result:

```
def regex():
    data_rnr = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["BORROWER ADDRESS"])
    pincoderegex=re.compile(r'\s([\w]+)\s([\d]{6})')
    data_rnr['BORROWER CITY_NAME']='default value'
    data_rnr['BORROWER CITY_PINCODE']='default value'
    for i in range(0,len(data_rnr['BORROWER ADDRESS'])):
        try:
            data_rnr['BORROWER CITY_NAME'][i]=pincoderegex.search(data_rnr['BORROWER ADDRESS'][i]).groups()[0]
            data_rnr['BORROWER CITY_PINCODE'][i]=pincoderegex.search(data_rnr['BORROWER ADDRESS'][i]).groups()[1]
        except:
            pass
    return data_rnr
%timeit regex()

2.1 ms ± 125 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

                                    BORROWER ADDRESS BORROWER CITY_NAME BORROWER CITY_PINCODE
0  87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Delhi 11...              Delhi                110059
1  87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Paris 93...              Paris                930000
2  87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Somewher...          Somewhere                115800
3                                        Wrong stuff      default value         default value
4  87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Bombay 1...             Bombay                148444
```

Using the one line code I got this result:

```
def pandasExtract():
    data_rnr = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["BORROWER ADDRESS"])
    return pd.concat([data_rnr, data_rnr['BORROWER ADDRESS'].str.extract(r'\s(?P<BORROWER_CITY_NAME>[\w]+)\s(?P<BORROWER_CITY_PINCODE>[\d]{6})')], axis=1)
%timeit pandasExtract()

1.1 ms ± 6.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

                                    BORROWER ADDRESS BORROWER_CITY_NAME BORROWER_CITY_PINCODE
0  87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Delhi 11...              Delhi                110059
1  87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Paris 93...              Paris                930000
2  87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Somewher...          Somewhere                115800
3                                        Wrong stuff                NaN                   NaN
4  87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Bombay 1...             Bombay                148444
```

But if you absolutely want to fill the `NaN` values it takes more time (still faster than your code):

```
def pandasExtractWithoutNan():
   data_rnr = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["BORROWER ADDRESS"])
   return pd.concat([data_rnr, data_rnr['BORROWER ADDRESS'].str.extract(r'\s(?P<BORROWER_CITY_NAME>[\w]+)\s(?P<BORROWER_CITY_PINCODE>[\d]{6})').fillna('default value')], axis=1)
%timeit pandasExtractWithoutNan()

1.57 ms ± 21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

                                    BORROWER ADDRESS BORROWER_CITY_NAME BORROWER_CITY_PINCODE
0  87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Delhi 11...              Delhi                110059
1  87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Paris 93...              Paris                930000
2  87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Somewher...          Somewhere                115800
3                                        Wrong stuff      default value         default value
4  87 F/F Place Opp. C-2, Uttam Nagar NA Bombay 1...             Bombay                148444
```

The documentation of the Pandas functions I used:

> [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas.Series.str.extract): extract the patterns found in the Series.
>
> [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html): fill the missing values by the value given.
>
> [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html): concat a list of DataFrames on the axis given.

Comment: Thanks @Smiley Prod for the detail explanation.

Comment: You are welcome, don't hesitate to mark as the answer @Oliver Hao's or mine if you think that we answered your question it might help other people with a similar approach :).

Answer (score 4):

- `([\w]*)[\s]([\d]{6})` need 398 steps
- `([\w]+)\s([\d]{6})` need  290 steps
- `\b([\w]+)\s([\d]{6})` need  174 steps
- `\s([\w]+)\s([\d]{6})` need  131 steps

so, you can used `\s([\w]+)\s([\d]{6})` to improve efficiency

https://regex101.com/r/iLIXDI/1